# How use var in name in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

How can i use my rand in window name in the following code :

```
var rand = 185656;
setTimeout("win+rand+2 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank')",2000);
```

+rand+ not work

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Please stop using strings inside setTimeout like that... just use a function: `setTimeout(function() { win = window.open('url'+secid, '_blank') }, 2000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`. Pass a function instead and set your global property explicitly on `window`, which will allow you to use square bracket notation:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window["win" + rand + "2"] = window.open("url" + secid, "_blank");
}, 2000);
```

The reason for not passing a string to `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) is that it's an alias for `eval`, which can be dangerous.

What you currently have will generate a reference error. It's effectively like doing this, which is obviously never going to work:

```
"a" + "b" = "c"; // ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: Thank you for being the only one, other than me in the comments, to advise against passing a string...

Comment: Thank you ,  can you please answer my last question? I wonder how to use var in funtion name like  funtion one+rand+()  inwhich rand is var and one is name

Comment: @user2100087 - The same way, but set the value of the property to be a function instead: `window["one" + rand] = function () {};`.

Answer (score 1):

It must be outside the quotes.

```
setTimeout("win"+rand+"2 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank')",2000);
```

Comment: thank you , How can I use rand in this code? win+rand+1 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank'); is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to "open" and "close" the String again:

```
setTimeout("win" + rand + "2 = window.open('url'" + secid + " , '_blank')",2000);
```

See **[this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html)** for the very basics.

Apart from that you shouldn't be passing executable code to `setTimeout` (it will get `eval`'d), use a function reference or an anonymous function to do so.

Also, constructiong var names like this is a bad idea as well. Look into objects and keys for that.

You could do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var rand = 185656;
    window['win' + rand + '2'] = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank'); //creates a global variable by adding a property to the global object
}, 2000);
```

Comment: thank you , How can I use rand in this code? win+rand+1 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank');   is it correct?

Comment: No, you can't use a runtime variable value for a variable name. You could do something like `window['win'+rand+'1']` as someone already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [don't pass strings to setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). Use the callback function instead. 
Then the variable has to be outside of the string (quotes) to be concatenated:

```
var rand = 185656;
setTimeout(function() {
    window["win" + rand + "2"] = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the quotes is making problem

```
setTimeout("win"+parseInt(rand)+"2 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank')",2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout("win" + rand + "2 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank')",2000);

Comment: thank you , How can I use rand in this code? win+rand+1 = window.open('url'+secid , '_blank'); is it correct?